# How to exclude the built file from coverage in webpack

Tags: webpack, code-coverage, webpack-2, istanbul

Following [this guide](https://medium.com/@scbarrus/how-to-get-test-coverage-on-react-with-karma-babel-and-webpack-c9273d805063), I've added istanbul-instrumenter to my test config to get an 'unbundled' coverage report that shows the rest of my files. However, the bundled test file is still shown, in `build/`:

```
----------------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------------|
File                        |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines |Uncovered Lines |
----------------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------------|
All files                   |    70.78 |    36.36 |    69.23 |    60.95 |                |
 build                      |    67.39 |    31.03 |    66.67 |    53.93 |                |
  tests.js                  |    67.39 |    31.03 |    66.67 |    53.93 |... 208,209,211 |
 src/routes/Home            |      100 |       75 |      100 |      100 |                |
  index.js                  |      100 |       75 |      100 |      100 |             11 |
 src/routes/Home/components |      100 |       75 |      100 |      100 |                |
  HomeView.js               |      100 |       75 |      100 |      100 |             18 |
----------------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------------|
✨  Done in 14.19s.
```

Here is my test config so far. I thought that excluding `build` in the istanbul-instrumenter-loader clause would do it, but it doesn't seem to:

```
var nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
var path = require('path');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

var project = require('../project.config');
const inProject = path.resolve.bind(path, project.basePath);
const inProjectSrc = (file) => inProject(project.srcDir, file);
const __DEV__ = project.env === 'development';

const extractStyles = new ExtractTextPlugin({
  filename: 'styles/[name].[contenthash].css',
  allChunks: true,
  disable: __DEV__
});

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    main: ['./tests/test-bundler.js']
  },
  target: 'node',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve('./build', project.basePath),
    filename: 'build/tests.js'
  },
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  module: {
    rules: [            
      {
        test: /\.js?$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                        options: {
                            cacheDirectory: true,
                            plugins: [
                                'babel-plugin-transform-class-properties',
                                'babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import',
                                [
                                    'babel-plugin-transform-runtime',
                                    {
                                        helpers: true,
                                        polyfill: false, // we polyfill needed features in src/normalize.js
                                        regenerator: true
                                    },
                                ],
                                [
                                    'babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread',
                                    {
                                        useBuiltIns: true // we polyfill Object.assign in src/normalize.js
                                    },
                                ],
                            ],
                            presets: [
                                'babel-preset-react',
                                ['babel-preset-env', {
                                    targets: {
                                        ie9: true,
                                        uglify: true,
                                        modules: false
                                    }
                                }],
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ],
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
        {
                test: /\.(sass|scss)$/,
                use: [
          'css-loader?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]',
          'sass-loader',
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(gif|png|jpe?g|svg)$/i,
                loaders: [
                    'file-loader',
                    {
                        loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
                        query: {
                            progressive: true,
                            optipng: {
                                optimizationLevel: 7
                            },
                            gifsicle: {
                                interlaced: false
                            },
                            pngquant: {
                                quality: '65-90',
                                speed: 4
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                // delays coverage til after tests are run, fixing transpiled source
                // coverage error
                enforce: 'post', 
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /(tests|node_modules|bower_components|build)\//,
                loader: 'istanbul-instrumenter-loader'
            }
    ]
    },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
  }
};
```

How do I ensure that the entry point `build/tests.js` is not used in the calculation of coverage?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your `exclude` regex is not working as expected. In which environment are you running your project?

Anyway since you want to run the coverage suite on your `src` folder only, you might invert exclude/include logic and go with (remember to require Node's `path`):

```
{
   enforce: 'post', 
   test: /\.js$/,
   include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
   loader: 'istanbul-instrumenter-loader'
}
```

Comment: That's a good point about the `include` property. However, the results are the same. (This is running on OSX.)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and tried below by adding folderNames' and was successful in excluding 
all files under those folders from coverage report

```
{
   enforce: 'post', 
   loader: 'istanbul-instrumenter-loader'
   exclude: [ /(<folderName1>|<folderName2>|node_modules|\.spec\.ts$)/, ],
}
```

Note: I am using the combination karma + webpack + istanbul